# Idiom, common phrase crossword puzzle challenge

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. Recklessly run around
2. Make things up
3. A big mistake is made
4. Better be independent
5. King among Kings
6. buried talent
7. Become a bandit
8. To do a good job, you must prepare your tools
9. give as charity
10. die for a cause

A. Crisscrossing

B. Do whatever you want

C. Winner writes the history

D. Trespassing (more commonly used in Cantonese)

E. nonsense

F. Looking for trouble

G. Before the army can move

H. Never say no

I. busy traffic

J. late bloomer

K. Want for nothing

L. Don't do things to people you don't want to be done to you

- If the blank one is too hard, you can try this one with additional hints

> [image: more hints]

Text version by Becky 李蓓 (you can type the missing characters directly on the ＃ marks)

> ```
> ．．．．．．．．．．．．．  Across    
> ．．．．①．．②．．．．．  ③ Crisscrossing
> ．③④＃＃．．＃．⑤．．．  ⑥ Do whatever you want
> ．．＃．＃．．⑥＃＃＃．．  ⑦ Winner writes the history
> ．．＃．⑦⑧＃＃．＃．．．  ⑨ Trespassing (more commonly used in cantonese)
> ．⑨＃．．＃．．．＃．．．  ⑩ nonsense
> ．．．⑩＃＃＃．⑪＃＃＃．  ⑪ Looking for trouble
> ．．．＃．＃．．．＃．．．  ⑫ Before the army can move
> ．．．＃．．．⑫＃＃＃．．  ⑬ Never say no
> ．．．⑬⑭＃＃．．＃．⑮．  ⑯ busy traffic
> ．．．．＃．．．．＃．＃．  ⑰ late bloomer
> ．．⑯＃＃＃．．⑰＃＃＃．  ⑲ Want for nothing
> ．．．．＃．⑱．．．．＃．  ⑳ Don't do things to people you don't want to be done to you
> ．⑲＃＃＃．＃．．．．．．  
> ．．．．⑳＃＃＃＃㉑＃＃．  Down
> ．．．．．．＃．．＃．．．  ① A big mistake is made
> ．．．．．．．．．．．．．  ② Become a bandit
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ④ Recklessly run around
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑤ To do a good job, you must prepare your tools
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑧ King among Kings
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑩ Make things up
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑭ Better be independent
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑮ die for a cause
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑱ buried talent
> 　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ㉑ give as charity
> ```

And here are the hints in both traditional and simplified.

> ```
>  ．．．．．．．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．．．．．．．．
>  ．．．．大．．＃．．．．．     ．．．．大．．＃．．．．．
>  ．＃＃交＃．．＃．＃．．．     ．＃＃交＃．．＃．＃．．．
>  ．．＃．＃．．为＃＃＃．．     ．．＃．＃．．為＃＃＃．．
>  ．．＃．＃＃败＃．＃．．．     ．．＃．＃＃敗＃．＃．．．
>  ．＃撞．．＃．．．＃．．．     ．＃撞．．＃．．．＃．．．
>  ．．．＃＃＃谈．＃＃生＃．     ．．．＃＃＃談．＃＃生＃．
>  ．．．中．王．．．必．．．     ．．．中．王．．．必．．．
>  ．．．＃．．．＃草＃＃．．     ．．．＃．．．＃草＃＃．．
>  ．．．＃＃＃应．．＃．＃．     ．．．＃＃＃應．．＃．＃．
>  ．．．．人．．．．＃．＃．     ．．．．人．．．．＃．＃．
>  ．．＃流＃＃．．＃器＃＃．     ．．＃流＃＃．．＃器＃＃．
>  ．．．．＃．＃．．．．仁．     ．．．．＃．＃．．．．仁．
>  ．＃＃无＃．才．．．．．．     ．＃＃無＃．才．．．．．．
>  ．．．．＃＃＃欲＃＃＃＃．     ．．．．＃＃＃欲＃＃＃＃．
>  ．．．．．．＃．．＃．．．     ．．．．．．＃．．＃．．．
>  ．．．．．．．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．．．．．．．．
> ```

Comment: 这个问题算是社区活动吗？is this question a community recreation?

Comment: In the process of solving the puzzle, one can learn a lot about the language, doing research to get the answer is beneficial to the users too.

Comment: I'd encourage the use of the spoiler syntax for answers to puzzle questions.

Comment: An exciting contest!

Comment: @T-Pioneer You solve it in 5 minutes, Next time, no text hints and the description hints will not be so obvious

Comment: Is that text hide what you wanted? Revert it if you didn't

Comment: @dROOOze Thanks, I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! I used simplified Chinese...

Don't be too cruel to me(from a Soviet song I just listened), I know most of members still didn't see this, so hide my answer for several hours if you want...

> [image: My Answer]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111763/discussion-on-answer-by-t-pioneer-idiom-common-phrase-crossword-puzzle-challeng).